# Загрузка страницы с выполненными скриптами HttpClient

Tags: java, url, httpclient

Есть задача - зайти на сайт под аккаунт используя известные куки от него и скачать загруженный сайт от лица этого аккаунта. Под аккаунтом c известными куками зайти удалось благодаря коду ниже, но сайт скачивается шаблонным, т.е. к сайту не применяются изменения скриптов(js), при таком подключении сайт не формирует полноценную страницу такую, которую можем видеть если сами зайдём через браузер. Возможно ли с помощью `HttpClient` сымитировать нормальный вход на страницу и скачать уже изменённую страницу с выполненными скриптами?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(test());
}

public static String test() {

    Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
    cookies.put("cookie1", "value1");
    cookies.put("cookie2", "value2");
    cookies.put("cookie3", "value3");
    cookies.put("cookie4", "value4");

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cookies.entrySet()) {
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        cookie.setDomain(".google.com"); //for example
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(LINK);

    String responseString;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            responseString = out.toString();
            out.close();
        } else {
            // Close the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю, он не предназначен для этого. Ведь это же не браузер..

Comment: Думаю, необходимо разобраться что надо и для чего и попытаться найти другое решение.

Comment: С некоторыми оговорками решали эти вопросы в JavaFX - имеется встроенный браузер. Так же можно загуглись Java Headless browser - это реализации браузеров без UI.